# Сортировка объектов с двумя параметрами в ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

*Я только начал изучать Java и возникла трудность.*

Есть класс Dog, есть ArrayList с пятью объектами класса Dog,которые имеют имя и возраст. Нужно их вывести в первый список младше 5 лет, во второй старше. Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: А при чем тут сортировка? Это называется фильтрация.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Прошу прощения, за, возможно, некорректный вопрос. Проблема для меня в том, что я не понимаю, как вывести в консоль список объектов класса Dog младше 5 лет. В результате нужно, что бы в консоль вывелось два списка - один с именами и возрастом младше 5 лет, во второй старше.

Comment: @GreyBear обновил [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/918852/218293). Надеюсь что решил проблему. Если ответ помог вам, плюсаните его, нажав стрелочку вверх рядом с ним. Если он решил вашу проблему, примите его, нажав галочку рядом с ним.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если переменные публичные, то используйте конструкцию `Dog.имя_переменной`. Если приватные, то используйте [геттеры/сеттеры](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1928-getterih-i-setterih). Я предполагаю, что переменные публичные(хотя правильно использовать геттеры/сеттеры).

Дано 3 листа - обычный с 5'ю объектами(`dogList`), для объектов у которых возраст меньше 5(`listLessFive`) и больше 5(`listMoreFive`), `age` - переменная в классе `Dog`, обозн. возраст.

```
for(int i = 0; i < dogList.size(); i++) {
   if(dogList.get(i).age < 5)
     listLessFive.add(dogList.get(i));
   else
     listMoreFive.add(dogList.get(i));
}
```

P.S. Кстати да, соглашусь с [комментарием](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/918850/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-arraylist/918852#comment1515279_918850) Kromster.

[UPD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/918850/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-arraylist/918852#comment1515281_918850):

Для вывода списка объектов используется метод [`foreach`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24109978/7150209):

```
listLessFive.forEach(System.out::println);
listMoreFive.forEach(System.out::println);
```

[UPD2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/918850/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-arraylist#comment1515302_918852).
Для вывода имен и возрастов исп. цикл [`foreach`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10168146/7150209):

```
    for(Dog dog : listLessFive) {
        System.out.println(dog.name + " | " +dog.age);
    }
    for(Dog dog : listMoreFive) {
        System.out.println(dog.name + " | " +dog.age);
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, возможно, это именно то, что нужно. Но есть один вопрос. Как сделать, что бы списки listLessFive и listMoreFive выводили не только age, но и name? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @GreyBear они не выводят имя или возраст. В комментарии вы писали, что вам надо вывести список объектов. Ответ я изменю, но пожалуйста, формируйте более понятный вопрос(а вообще почитайте [справку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), если не читали).

Comment: Это свойственно всем, начинающим изучать ООП. Советую хорошенько почитать про ООП у того же Эккеля в "Философии Java", например. Грубо говоря, вы не можете сравнивать объекты сами по себе - `dogList.get(0) > dogList.get(2)` - это не верно. Всегда мы оперируем их полями, которые получаем либо с помощью геттеров, либо как в вашем случае показал Anton238: `dogList.get(0).age > dogList.get(2).age`, если они публичные.